# Execute .exe in php and fill input

Tags: php, exe

Firstly, sorry for my English.
Is it possible to start .exe program with php script and pass input after the program has started. I can't use command line arguments.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int a, b;
    cin>>a>>b;
    return a+b;
}
```

Comment: what is the type of `a` and `b`?

Comment: Sorry. I've updated the code above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [popen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php) or [proc_open](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php).

```
<?php
    $handle = popen('echo 1 2 | /path/to/compiled-program', 'r');
    $read = fread($handle, 32);
    echo $read;
    pclose($handle);
?>
```

BTW, your c++ program does not compile.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{   
    int a, b;
    cin >> a >> b;
    cout << a + b << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the examples, code and answer in general. Sorry for bad cpp code, I know only basic cpp syntax.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to write to your executable stdin, use `popen`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php

If you need to write to stdin and get results from stdout, use `proc_open`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can there are several functions that do that

1. [exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)
2. [system()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php)
3. [passthru()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php)
4. [popen()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php)
5. [proc_open()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php)